# jQuery UI Tabs: JSON not displaying

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm using jquery ui tabs with ajax.

Ajax will face a JSON content like this.

```
[
  {
    "title"   :"a note",
    "type"    :"text",
    "content" :"MY FIRST NOTE!"
  },
  {
    "title"   :"two note",
    "type"    :"text",
    "content" :"MY FIRST NOTE <b>if html works<\/b> i should pay attention to this!"
  }
]
```

I'm using this code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        cache : false,
        ajaxOptions : {
            cache : false,
            dataType : 'json',
            dataFilter : function(result) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(result);
                return data;
            },
            error : function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                $(" anchor.hash ").html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " + "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

(i've seen this question [Loading JSON-encoded AJAX content into jQuery UI tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785548/loading-json-encoded-ajax-content-into-jquery-ui-tabs))

The JSON file (is generated by php) is correctly loaded and I have validated it using JSONLint but the tab remain white and the content isn't loaded, can you help me?

It's the first time that i work with JSON and Ajax so forgive me if I'm doing some stupid error

EDIT: the json content is sent with a content type = application/json, removing the content type it display the json but i want to parse the json file using jquery is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried using  :  return data.content instead of return data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should not call `$.parseJSON(result);` since you specified  `dataType : 'json'` (look at my answer to this question [Why is 'jQuery.parseJSON' not necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111184/why-is-jquery-parsejson-not-necessary/9111201#9111201) ) and so jQuery parses the response for you. Looking at the other example you should also return

```
       dataFilter : function(result) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(result);
            return data.content;
        },
```

EDIT - letting `dataType: 'json'` this should be ok

```
       dataFilter : function(result) {
            return result.content;
        },
```

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi yes but you should let `dataType: 'json'` and just `return result.content` i added that to my answer

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi that's strange, anyway the important thing is that it works

Answer (score 2):

The content isn't properly loaded to the tab because of this part:

```
dataType : 'json',
dataFilter : function(result) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(result);
    return data;
}
```

You receive data as json, so `result` is javascript object. But `$.parseJSON()` requires string, not object ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)). It works - as you write - when `dataType : 'html'` because with this setting data is returned as text.

To fix it you can either set `dataType : 'html'` or get rid of `dataFilter` part. When you ask for data in json format jQuery calls `$.parseJSON()` internally.

**UPDATE**: One more information why you don't get any errors with `$.parseJSON()` - As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently [see docs too](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

I found it simpler to return `false` to the `beforeLoad` handler and send a `getJSON` request from within the `beforeLoad` handler. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785548/loading-json-encoded-ajax-content-into-jquery-ui-tabs).