# Why is 'jQuery.parseJSON' not necessary?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i'm doing an ajax request with query and wondering why my response is already a JS object.

If i do a

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

'obj' is null, but i can use 'response' as an array of js objects.

This is not really a problem, but i would like to understand this behavior.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens when you make an AJAX call and specify the dataType JSON jQuery calls jQuery.parseJSON on the response for you. In fact you can specify what function to call depending on the dataType as you can se from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> converters(added 1.5)
>   Map Default: {"* text": window.String, "text
>   html": true, "text json": jQuery.parseJSON, "text xml":
>   jQuery.parseXML} A map of dataType-to-dataType converters. Each
>   converter's value is a function that returns the transformed value of
>   the response

So if you make a call like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: yoururl,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    //data is already a json
  }
```

If you don't specify a dataType jQuery tries to guess it

> dataTypeString   Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or
>   html)
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none
>   is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of
>   the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield
>   a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and
>   anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and
>   the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:
>
> "xml": Returns a XML document that can be processed via jQuery.
>   "html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated
>   when inserted in the DOM. "script": Evaluates the response as
>   JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Disables caching by appending
>   a query string parameter, "*=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache
>   option is set to true. Note: This will turn POSTs into GETs for
>   remote-domain requests. "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and
>   returns a JavaScript object. In jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in
>   a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is
>   thrown. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)
>
>   "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra
>   "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables
>   caching by appending a query string parameter, "*=[TIMESTAMP]", to the
>   URL unless the cache option is set to true.
>     "text": A plain text
>   string. multiple, space-separated values:
>     As of jQuery 1.5, jQuery can
>   convert a dataType from what it received in the Content-Type header to
>   what you require. For example, if you want a text response to be
>   treated as XML, use "text xml" for the dataType. You can also make a
>   JSONP request, have it received as text, and interpreted by jQuery as
>   XML: "jsonp text xml." Similarly, a shorthand string such as "jsonp
>   xml" will first attempt to convert from jsonp to xml, and, failing
>   that, convert from jsonp to text, and then from text to xml.

Comment: additionally, the server can also set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, and jQuery will *best-guess* the response format.

Comment: "*of course you must set the correct headers server side*" is incorrect. jQuery *trusts* what you set `dataType` to. It only checks the headers if it has to *best guess*.

Answer (score 4):

It pretty much depends which `dataType` you pass into your jQuery ajax request. This might happen implict by calling `.getJSON()` or directly using `$.ajax()`.

However, if you omit the `dataType`, jQuery trys to do some magic and guesses which data was received. <strike>As for JSON data, it uses a simple regular expression to check if a response looks like a JSON-string and if so, it automatically parses it for you.</strike>
jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response.

So always be precise and tell jQuery which type of data you expect.

Comment: It simply checks content-type header or overriden mimetype, there is no parsing of the response content to see what type it is

Comment: @Esailija: true fixed that. I was confused about the validation regexp `parseJSON` uses internally.

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour of jQuery's ajax method is to analyse the response and return it as the most appropriate data type. If your response looks like JSON, therefore, it will be converted to a JavaScript object/array.

You can override this behaviour by setting the `dataType` attribute in the ajax settings.

Answer (score 2):

if you specify the `dataType` as `json` the jquery parses the response for you like

```
$.ajax({
...
dataType:'json',
...
});
```

same is the case with [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

this is how the source code for `getJSON` looks like

```
getJSON: function( url, data, callback ) {
return jQuery.get( url, data, callback, "json" );
},
```

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L283

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.converters["text json"] === jQuery.parseJSON
```

I.E it will run the function everytime json response is detected automatically or explicitly set by yourself

Comment: This is not "*the reason*" why the object is returned. This makes it *possible* for the object to be returned (as there is now a converter from `* -> text` and then `text -> json`), but it's the `dataType` or best-guess which actually does the conversion.

Comment: @Matt Yes it is, if you make that function return "hello", all responses detected json will return "hello" to you. I am using this to preprocess `for(;;);` out of all responses.