# jquery ajax web method works but unable to use data

Tags: jquery, json, web-services

My web service call returns this into data1

```
"{"d":"PCIS Follow Add ID and Codes when printed"}"
```

I learne that when using jquery with asp.net i must use data1.d

however when i try to do alert(data.d);

i get undefined returned even though data.d value shows as

```
"{"d":"PCIS Follow Add ID and Codes when printed"}"
```

any ideas on how i can use this information

the web service should be returning a string

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Services/WorkService.asmx/WorkDescription",
                data: "{'workUnitId' : '" + $("option:selected", $(dropdown)).text() + "','id': '" + combobox.val() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data1) {
                var jsObject = JSON.parse(data1.d);
            alert(jsObject);                   
 combobox.attr("_tooltip", data1.d);    
                }    
            });
        },
```

Comment: will be better if you post us your webservice call using jquery

Comment: i added the web service example

Comment: please check your json string returned by the webservice call using http://www.jsonlint.com or any other json validator. you can find the json in mozilla firebug net panels xhr tab

Comment: Shouldn't `dataType` be `json`, not `text`?

Comment: check if adding `?workUnitId=...` will help, it could be server issue

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin yes, because if you specify the dataType jQuery "believes" you and doesn't try to "guess" the format of the response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should set `json` as `dataType`

```
 dataType:"json",
```

because if you specify `text` jQuery won't parse the response (if you specify `json` jQuery calls `$.parseJSON()` on the response)

Look at my answer in this question [Why is 'jQuery.parseJSON' not necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111184/why-is-jquery-parsejson-not-necessary/9111201#9111201)

EDIT your server should return

```
{"d":"PCIS Follow Add ID and Codes when printed"}
```

withouth the starting and trailing `"`

Comment: problem is i just changed it to text it was json before and wasnt working

Comment: @bugz if you just call `alert(data1)` what do you get?

Comment: @bugz i edited my answer, maybe before it didn't work because it wasn't valid json

Comment: i get [object Object] this is after i switched my dataType to json

Normal I should use data1.d

Comment: @bugz if you get  [object Object] it is correct, if you use Chrome (or Firefox with firebug) you could do  `console.log(data1)` and see post here what you see in your "console" panel

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
var jsObject = JSON.parse('{"hello":"world"}');
alert(jsObject.hello);
</script>
```