# Issue getting first item from JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

```
$('#data').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:        'richiesta.php',
        type:       'POST',
        dataType:   'json',
        data: {
            value: this.value
        },
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#textfield').val(JSON.stringify(data));
        $('#results').val('Descrizione codice: ' + data[0].descrizione_codice);
    });
});
```

`richiesta.php` is just a file that triggers some functions to get the JSON.
`#textfield` is correctly populated with the raw JSON, so everything is working properly.

I can't figure out how to output the first item of the JSON identified by the name `descrizione_codice` in `#results`.

The JSON is valid, here's an example selecting one option (truncated):

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "codice_comparto":"PRO",
         "descrizione_codice":"Competenze fisse per il personale a tempo indeterminato",
         "codice_siope":"1101",
         "descrizione_ente":"",
         "ricerca":false,
         "idtable":"000717409-1101",
         "cod_ente":"000717409",
         "anno":"2014",
         "periodo":"12",
         "codice_gestionale":"1101",
         "imp_uscite_att":"756",
         "importo_2013":"37718576",
         "importo_2014":"32810124",
         "importo_2015":null
      }
   ],
   "cosa":false
}
```

I'm doing something wrong is that data(0).descrizione_codice as Firebug tells me "data is not a function"..

I'm not using `$.parseJSON` because jQuery [already parses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688944/1342772) `data` correctly thanks to the datatype.

I put up a test page **[here](https://multiformeingegno.it/testsoldipubblici/webpage.php)**. You can request the JSON response selecting an option from the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your JSON structure you should be able to access array as `data.data`

```
.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data.data[0].descrizione_codice);
});
```

Comment: Yep. Worked! Accepting in 4 mins

Comment: I'm getting the following error... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @iamchriswick You need to inspect what `data` is. Check `console.log(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#results').val('Descrizione codice: ' + data.data[0].descrizione_codice);
```

1. First **data** is your actual *js variable*
2. Second **data** is your *array inside JSON* named "data" where we access first element's property named "descrizione_codice"

Hope it clarifies